# How to find item in array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to retrieve data from a json file and then match it with the value of an existing variable and if the variable value matches the data in json it will display a message "a" and if it does not match it will display a message "b".

the json file is like this

```
["23435","87567", "34536","45234","34532","65365"]
```

Comment: That's an array not a JSON format file. Those are the only contents in the file?

Comment: oh so it's just an array ? . yes the content is just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to find a value in an array.

You can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
    const array = ["23435","87567", "34536","45234","34532","65365"]

    const aConstant = "23435"

    return (<div>{ array.includes(aConstant) ? 'a' : 'b' }</div>)
```

Same thing with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
    const array = ["23435","87567", "34536","45234","34532","65365"]

    const aConstant = "23435"

    return (<div>{ array.indexOf(aConstant) !== -1 ? 'a' : 'b' }</div>)
```

You can also try [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
    const array = ["23435","87567", "34536","45234","34532","65365"]

    const aConstant = "23435"

    return (<div>{ Boolean(array.filter( x => x === aConstant)) ? 'a' : 'b' }</div>)
```

And even [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
    const array = ["23435","87567", "34536","45234","34532","65365"]

    const aConstant = "23435"

    return (<div>{ array.find( x => x === aConstant) ? 'a' : 'b' }</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a proper JSON format file, you can load it in simply as a string:

```
import arrayFile from './arrayFile.txt';
```

Then, if your file is truly just an array hidden with nothing else, you can do something like this to get it into an array format:

```
const newArray = JSON.parse(arrayFile);
```